# Separating out Areas using subdomains completely from main site Mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have an area as `Admin` . And it has got a controller as `SigninController` . Now this Area is for Admin Area . which I am supposed to map as `http://admin.localhost/`

Now what Happens is I also have a `SigninController` in root . So I currently have to invoke the admin Signin as `http://localhost:80/Admin/Signin`. and For root `http://localhost/Signin`

What I want is to completely separate out the admin area until and unless it is invoked by a subdomain .

I dont want the use to hit the url even if by chance it is `http://localhost:80/admin/signin` . He shouldn't be routed to admin signin area . It should be only available via the subdomain url i.e via

`http://admin.localhost:80/Admin/Signin` or `http://admin.localhost:80/Signin`.

It should be such that the area signin is always invoked when the request url is through a subdomain configuration and not from the root of the project with area name in the url .

How to do that any guidance ?

Comment: why not two different apps? Do not use areas.

Comment: @Bart the question isnt about two different apps . But question is about can I separate the two different areas  to completely two different subdomains . I might have several segments ( domain specific) funtionalities which I want to divide it into subdomains for the main site .